# IBM App connect Applications Memory Utilization

Tags: websphere, ibm-app-connect, resource-utilization

I am Tring to calculate the memory consumed by each application in the integration server associated with integration node and the environment I work on is Linux. I tried more than one thing but non of them list the memory utilization for each application.

I tried a too named valgrind but it didnot work and tied some linux command but not working also
thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

Try using mqsichangeflowstats to extract information.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/app-connect/11.0.0?topic=command-mqsichangeflowstats-windows-linux-aix-systems